# How to edit a grid row to remove the underline

Tags: c#, wpf

in this, the 'Residents' is underlined. how do  I remove the underline?

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="31" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBoxTitleHeader}" Grid.Row="1">Residents</TextBlock>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
```

Answer (score 2):

The underline is not due to the XAML you showed.  It's likely defined within the `TextBoxTitleHeader` style you're using.

You can likely remove it by removing or changing that style, ie:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="1">Residents</TextBlock>
```